# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' on running React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ts-jest, react-typescript

I am trying to learn about React and how to make an api call and display a list of items.

Here is my code:

App.tsx:

```
  function App() { 
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [err, setError] = useState({}); 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://demo4666569.mockable.io/groups')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => setJobs(res))
    .catch(err => setError(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {jobs.length > 0 ? <Job jobs={jobs} /> : (<Loader />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Job.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { DetailsList, DetailsListLayoutMode, IColumn } from '@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList';
import { IJob } from "../interfaces/IJob.interfaces";

export interface IDetailsListBasicExampleProps {
  jobs: IJob[];
}

export default class Job extends React.Component<IDetailsListBasicExampleProps> {
  private _columns: IColumn[];

  constructor(props:IDetailsListBasicExampleProps) {
    super(props);

    this._columns = [
      { key: 'column1', name: 'Identifier', fieldName: 'Identifier', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
      { key: 'column2', name: 'ObjectType', fieldName: 'ObjectType', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true }
    ];   
  }
  
  public render(): JSX.Element {      
      return(
        <div>
        <br />
          <DetailsList
            items={this.props.jobs}
            columns={this._columns}
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}              
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
            ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
            ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
            checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"              
        />
        <br />
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

```
export interface IJob {
    Identifier: string;
    ObjectType: string;
}
```

I created a test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```

On running

```
pnpm start
```

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: There seems to be a [couple of related issues](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Unexpected+token+%27export%27+is%3Aclosed) in the fluentui list. This doesn't appear to be a problem with _your_ code

Comment: which version of node are you using ?

Comment: v19.7.0 node version